# Tetration Power Series

Tags: functional-analysis, fractional-iteration, tetration

While reading through the [Citizendium article on tetration](https://en.citizendium.org/wiki/tetration), the first hyper-operation above exponentiation, I came across a power series approximate of tetration. The article said that it got the series coefficients from cauchy’s integral formula for the nth derivative of a function. There are a few questions I have. Firstly how did they get the power series coefficients given only the recursive definition for tetration? Secondly I’m familiar with the fact that you can determine the nth iterate of the exponential function through Carleman matrices and then plug 1 into the function and obtain ***tet***(n) for all n, will this function converge to the same function represented through the power series expansion of tetration?

Comment: I would not call tetration (a term that I utterly detest) the "fourth (hyper-)operation above exponentiation". Rather, I would call it the *first* operation above exponentiation, specifically "iterated exponentiation", and in particular, "continuously iterated exponentiation". You might want to look at this 1960 paper of Erdos & Jabotinsky, and later ones that reference it: https://static.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1960-07.pdf.

Comment: Your questions are probably more suitable to the discussion page for the article you link to.

Comment: Additional to Daniel Asimov's comment, I would always say: "... tetration, the ***expected*** fourth..." or "... tetration, the ***attempted*** fourth..." because it is still not established, that such a function is meaningfully constructible for the general case at all. If I recall correctly, even in the citizendium article the author has let it as a hypothese (although his attempt to provide evidence for it). *Btw., I would not comment this way in MSE, but in a forum like MO I'd like to see what I think is more professional style.*

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration there is a link to a paper which supposedly proves that tetration is holomorphic: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10444-017-9524-1

Comment: In my papers focused on (strong) integer tetration, I use both "tetration" and "hyper-4" as synonyms. Anyway, my favourite extension of hyper-4 to the complex plane is the one provided by William Paulsen (see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10444-018-9615-7). The discussion is still open on tetrationforum, with some interesting outcomes as the following thread https://tetrationforum.org/showthread.php?tid=1762.

Comment: I thought Kneser's Tetration gave a unique solution of extending tetration as a holomorphic function the complex plane (minus the real axis) and so its power series at various points became the canonical power series for tetration. Clicking around on @Marco's tetration forum link suggests that there is still activity to come up with different fractional analogs of tetration. Is there something undesirable about Kneser's solution that motivates people to keep looking for other forms of tetration with different power series? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Complex_heights

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal - there exists a *provisorical* software solution for the Kneser-Ansatz; but the author (S.Levenstein) conceded, that its correctness needs external verification. It's true that in the tetrationforum-biotop this is much accepted - even in its extension to other bases than $e$ and even to complex values of its arguments; and I don't know in which way Kouznetsov(citizendium) , Kouznetsov & Trappman's, Paulsen's, and recently J.D.Nixon's "beta" method are related to this. The Levenstein's implementation is impressive and may have the best chance to come out as canonical solution.

Comment: Gottfried Helms: The case of continuous iteration of an analytic function f : U —> ℂ near a fixed point (say at f(0) = 0) is nicely covered by Königs's Theorem: If |f'(0)| is neither 0 nor 1, then there exists a holomorphic family {f_t | t ∈ V} (where V is an open neighborhood of the origin) satisfying f_0 = f and f_s o f_t = f_(s+t) for all s and t with |s| < epsilon, |t| < epsilon) where s and t are complex. (For some epsilon > 0.)  In many cases, the iteration and its properties are satisfied for all s, t complex.

Comment: (continued) In most of those cases, there exist more than one way to define this. Thus ultimately depends on a choice of one specific branch of the complex logarithm.

Comment: @DanAsimov - thanks for your comment! Is by the analysis of Koenigs something about the order of epsilon known? By some (little educated) considerations on possible  trajectories over periodic points I came to the guess that that epsilon might be very small. (I've done one or two msg's on MO concerning periodic points but couldn't meaningfully resolve my doubts/establish a sound understanding)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms the "beta" method is not analytic. Tommy's improvement (of the beta) by the gaussian method is analytic. But is probably not equal to the Kneser. Tommy's method with $\exp(x) - \exp(-3/5 x)$ might be the same as Kneser.

Comment: @mick - as those concepts are not easily to decode practically: would you mind to give some numerical evidence for the two topoi you mentioned? Numerical comparision of the Kneser (by Levenstein?) and the Nixon's Beta and/or Tommy's solutions? *(At least for the sake of having redundance when I should try myself to implement&check)* That yould be a great service...

Comment: not so easy Gottfried , but it was somewhat in the forum